# When to capitalize the beginning of a quotation?

Tags: citations, citation-style, quotation

So I know (now) that if you quote a complete sentence and this sentence is syntactically set off from the rest of your sentence with a comma etc, one has to (according to the Turabian) capitalize the start of the quotation. However, I am wondering if "complete sentence" here includes sentences shortened with an ellipsis? The sentence is still "complete" grammatically but shortened.

In general I am not quite sure what "complete sentence" means. Does it mean that the sentence is a complete sentence in the original or that it can be a part of a longer sentence in the original that, however, grammatically still is a full sentence?

A sample complete sentence shortened with an ellipsis: "*As he pointed out, 'Fishes come in many colours...and can be found in many places*".

- is this a "complete sentence" shortened with an ellipsis in the Turabian
- would I in this case not capitalize "*fishes*"

Reference from Turabian:

> In most disciplines, you may change the initial letter
> of a quoted passage from capital to lowercase or from lowercase to capital without noting the change. If you weave the quotation into the syntax of your sentence, begin it with a lowercase letter. Otherwise, begin it with a capital letter if it begins with a complete sentence, with a lowercase letter if it does not.

On a related note, I have to admit that I only learned about this rule recently and before had assumed that it is fine to change capitalization of the beginning of a quote, as long as it is integrated into one's larger sentence.
Is this a great faux pas (it is in some of my published work) or forgivable?

Comment: Can you give an example sentence?

Comment: Are your publications in humanities, law or science?

Comment: I am in the humanities.

Comment: Does this assist ... https://www.servantsuniversity.com/run-in-quotations-in-turabian-format/

Comment: My question would be a) what is meant by "complete sentence" in the Turabian and b) what if such a complete sentence is shortened with an ellipsis but still has its beginning and end intact. Would I still say: "As he pointed out, 'Fishes come in many colours...and can be found in many places". Or would I in this case not capitalize "fishes".

Comment: Such "mechanical" style issues will depend on where you want to publish. Look for official advice from that place, a style guide or some such. Look for how previous authors have done the same thing.

Comment: @bobaFit that would suggest that there is no 'absolutely correct' way of doing it then? Style guides of journals aren't always clear about this I am afraid. So I can only go with the Turanian etc.

Comment: @IbnZubeira There is no absolute right way. Different journals will have different rules. If the "boss" changes at a journal the rules may change.

Comment: But there must be some guidelines? To be honest I am unhappy I didn't know about the capitalization rule I mentioned above before even though I have been in academia for years... But I guess if there is no absolutely correct way then there is also no absolutely incorrect way of doing it :)

Comment: Sometimes I see brackets used, when the original was not capitalized: "[F]ishes come in many colors..."

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave is a bit difficult to work with. Typically, at the end of the ellipsis, there should be a standalone 'sentence'.

With your example, one would rather go with

> As he pointed out, "Fishes come in many colours...and can be found in many places"

Or, if there's a stop at the end of colours

> As he pointed out, 'Fishes come in many colours....They can be found in many places".

If however, what you want to express is where fishes can be found, I'll go with

> Fishes can be found in many places

See:

- [Turabian 9 guide](https://library.stritch.edu/getmedia/8dc8e892-5a21-42fb-9e58-55643a1ef0ad/Turabian-9-Guide)
- Cross reference from Chicago: [Ellipses with Periods (CMOS 13.53)](https://library.stritch.edu/getmedia/8dc8e892-5a21-42fb-9e58-55643a1ef0ad/Turabian-9-Guide)

PS: though distinct, there are overlaps between Turabian and Chicago.

Comment: Thanks so much! One further query: What if one interrupts the quotation with one's own words in the middle? For instance: "As he explains, 'Fishes come in many colours' and they 'can be found in many places.' Would one still capitalize "Fishes"?

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by "The example you gave is a bit difficult to work with. Typically, at the end of the ellipse, there should be a standalone 'sentence'."? Usually an ellipsis is not always followed by a full sentence.